# Return type of Drools query and combining queries

Tags: drools

I have a situation where I need to check if there are 2 EObjects of type A. For that I have written a query like:

```
query checkA()
$r1 : EObject(eClass().getName() ==  "A")
$r2 : EObject(eClass().getName() ==  "A",this != $r1)
end
```

And in the same way if 3 EObjects of type B

```
query checkB()
$r1 : EObject(eClass().getName() ==  "B" , some_more_constraints)
$r2 : EObject(eClass().getName() ==  "B" , some_more_constraints,this != $r1)
$r3 : EObject(eClass().getName() ==  "B" , some_more_constraints,this != $r1,this != $r2)
end
```

And I need to check if either 2 EObjects of type A **OR** 3 EObjects of type B is there. I have a rule for that :

```
Rule "checking"
when
checkA()
||
checkB()
then
... do_something...
```

When I am running the rule, it is giving a ClassCastException exception.

It would be really helpful if you please help me understand why this is happening and answer the below two questions.
a) How can I implement this?
b) What is the return type of either of checkA() or checkB() queries ?

If I remove the '||' condition from the rule, then it is running fine without any error.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 important things to understand here:

1. Queries in Drools, when used in the `when` section of a rule, don't return a value.
2. The `||` operator doesn't work as a usual `or` operator in Drools.

### Queries in your rules

A query (without [unbounds arguments](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_queries_with_unbound_arguments)) in Drools, when used inside a the `when` section of a rule, behaves similar to having the same patterns you have in it copied into the rule.

Let's take for example the following DRL:

```
query strings()
  $s1: String()
  String(this != $s1)
end

rule "Test"
when
  strings()
then
  //do something...
end
```

When inserting 2 `Strings` (`s1` and `s2`) in the session, we will have 2 activations of the `Test` rule:

- Activation 1: `[s1, s2]`
- Activation 2: `[s2, s1]`

### `OR` between patterns

When Drools finds an || between the patterns of a rule, it basically splits the rule into 2. The biggest difference between this behaviour and a regular `or` in any other programming language is that in the case that both parts of the `or` operation are true, the rule will be activated twice.

So, for example, the following rule:

```
rule "Test"
when
  String(this == "ABC") ||
  String(this == "DEF")
then
  //Do something
end
```

will create 2 different rules in runtime:

```
rule "Test-1"
when
  String(this == "ABC")
then
  //Do something
end

rule "Test-2"
when
  String(this == "DEF")
then
  //Do something
end
```

One of the problems when using `||` is that you have to be very careful when using bound variables in your patterns, because you don't know whether they will contain a value or not.

**I guess your Exception is actually caused by how are you binding your variables in the when section of your rule**

---

I hope that now that you know a little bit more about how Drools works when using queries and the `||` operator, you will be able to trace down where and why the exception is happening.